# Converting Recursive Function

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, mergesort

I have a recursive function here, but it is causing overflow errors so I need to change it into a non-recursive function.  Any help on how to do that will be greatly appreciated!

```
void MergeSort(struct node** headRef)
{
    node* head = *headRef;
    node* a;
    node* b;
    if ((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL))
    {
        return;
    }

    FrontBackSplit(head, &a, &b);
    MergeSort(&a);
    MergeSort(&b);
    *headRef = SortedMerge(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Did you research that?

Comment: Is this an academic question? You could use the STL `sort` on a standard container otherwise. If you're wedded to this linked-list implementation we'd need to see `FrontBackSplit` too, I think, to analyse.

Comment: Yes I have to use a linked list.  And I put that function down below.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question - unless you're on a small embedded system, your stack should be able to handle thousands of nested calls. Your split should divide the list to be sorted in half. So if you are getting a stack overflow then you either have a list with many more elements than there are atoms in the universe, or you have an error in your `FrontBackSplit` function

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a tree-recursive function that overflows your stack, a straightforward way to transform it into a non-recursive one (that instead uses the heap) is to essentially allocate your own stack.

Every time your function would invoke itself with some arguments, instead stuff those arguments into a `struct`, and push that `struct` into a work queue (I say "queue", but the actual data structure could be a `std::stack` or `std::queue` depending on whether you want to process items in LIFO or FIFO order).  Now you can call your function in an iterative loop: iterate on that queue until it's empty, popping each set of arguments off and invoking your function with them (which could add new items to the work queue).